# Is there a C/C++ APIfor pkg-config?

Tags: c++, bash, pkg-config

I have a strange use case. I have a C++ program that compiles a library object and dynamically loads it at runtime. The library it compiles depends on a third party dependency, which so far I have been solving by manually hard coding the path and changing it when I switch computers.

Is there a way to call pkg-config from C++ to ask it if a library is installed and where? I know I could call it from a bash session and parse the output, but this is not what I want, I would like to call it directly instead of invoking a shell if that is possible.

Comment: `pkg-config` will only provide information if the *development* package for a given library is installed. That's unlikely on a non-developer system.

Comment: This project is made for research so it's reasonable to assume the package is sintalled, the problem is more that *where* it is installed changes from system to system.

Comment: Could you wrap your program in a package and add a dependency to the library you are using? This would solve your problem in an elegant way, you'll let the package system worry about the dependency and version compatibility.

Comment: The library that si generated is created using runtime information, which is why it's so convoluted. It depends on user input.

Even if the program itself is packaged, that doesn;t mean the library generated by the program will be.

Comment: `popen("pkg-config ...")`. It's still unclear - what will you do on a system that does not have pkg-config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a C/C++ APIfor pkg-config?

Yes, there is a C api. https://github.com/pkgconf/pkgconf/blob/master/libpkgconf/libpkgconf.h , which should get installed with `libpkgconf.so` shared library.